# Why do people add their own folder to the standard include path?

Tags: c, include, include-path

When looking at different interesting projects over at GitHub, I came across the following file:

https://github.com/charliesome/slash/blob/master/src/lib/regexp.c

It seems like he includes his own files the same way as standard headers:

```
#include <slash/lib/regexp.h>
```

Instead of this way:

```
#include "slash/lib/regexp.h"
```

I guess he changes the include path to make this possible, but my question is: why? Isn't the quote syntax made for situations like this (including your own header file)?

Answer (score 1):

For projects of moderate size and in particular installable ones, it's often more convenient to store headers in a separate directory like `include/` under the project root instead of next to the C files.

After adding this directory to the include path, the choice of `<>` or `""` becomes a stylistic one -- `""` is only necessary for relative paths or if you add include directories via `-iquote` instead of `-I`, which is not particulary common.

An argument for using `""` would be to explicitly mark headers as project-specific.

An argument for using `<>` would be that header inclusion will look the same in user and library code.

Answer (score 0):

It makes it easy to change the directory structure of your project by simply changing the include path in your Makefile. For example, you might have started out with all headers in `myproj/src` and you now want to have an extra `myproj/include` folder for all your headers.